# How do you query an object inside of a text field, to do something with it?

Tags: python, maya

I would like to know how to query a selection entered into a text field group, so I can do something with it. I have created a window to just translate an object that I loaded in the text field. The error is that cont is not defined.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as ml

def set_selected_name (text_field):
    cont = cmds.ls (selection = True)
    text_field = cmds.textFieldButtonGrp (text_field, edit = True,
                               text = ''.join (cont),
                               buttonLabel = '<<<<',
                               backgroundColor = [0.5098039215686274,
                                                  0.5098039215686274,
                                                  0.5098039215686274])
    return text_field

def translate_x(cont):
    cmds.setAttr( cont[0] + '.translateX', 10) 
       
def translate_y():
    cmds.setAttr( cont[0] + '.translateY', 10) 
       
def translate_z(*Args):        
    cmds.setAttr( cont[0] + '.translateZ', 10)




if cmds.window ('window1', q = 1, ex = 1):
    cmds.deleteUI ('window1')

cmds.window ('window1',
             title = 'Translate Attr',
             sizeable = 0,
             resizeToFitChildren = True,
             menuBar = 1)

cmds.rowLayout (numberOfColumns = 3)


cmds.separator (style = 'double',
                height = 6)

cmds.rowLayout (parent = 'window1',
                numberOfColumns = 4)

ddd = cmds.textFieldButtonGrp (editable = False,
                               text = 'Obj',
                               backgroundColor = [0.029495689326314183,
                                                  0.5488975356679637,
                                                  0.5488975356679637],
                               buttonLabel = '<<<<')

cmds.textFieldButtonGrp (ddd, edit = True,
                         buttonCommand = 'set_selected_name (ddd)')


cmds.separator (style = 'double',
                height = 6)

cmds.rowLayout (parent = 'window1',
                numberOfColumns = 6)

cmds.separator (style = 'double',
                height = 6)

cmds.button (command = 'translate_y()',
             backgroundColor = [1.0,
                                0.7300068665598535,
                                0.7300068665598535],
             label = 'Translate Y')

cmds.separator (style = 'double',
                height = 6)

cmds.button (command = 'translate_x(cont)',
             backgroundColor = [1.0,
                                0.9733272297245746,
                                0.7333333333333333],
             label = 'Translate X')

cmds.separator (style = 'double',
                height = 6)

cmds.button (command = 'translate_z()',
             backgroundColor = [0.7333333333333333,
                                1.0,
                                0.7600061036087586],
             label = 'Translate Z')

cmds.columnLayout (parent = 'window1')

cmds.separator (style = 'double',
                height = 3)

cmds.showWindow ('window1')

# ~ BABLAAM ~
```

Create any object you like, loaded into the text field and then try to translate with buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your code.

1. In the translate commands you always use cont[0]. cont is only used in the function `set_selected_name()` and is a local variable what means it is deleted as soon as the function is completed.
2. You can use a string as command in the button command, but this only works with static values. You should use lambdas to use functions with arguments.

The `cont` Problem *can* be solved by using a global variable, but it shouldn't since global variables are the source of all evil. A much more elegant way would be to enclose you UI in one python class and use instance variables to get the selection.

Answer (score 0):

I have adjusted the code to add the class as you recommended but still having the same issue. By not using the quotes in the button command I get this error when I try to run the script, instead of getting it when I press the button.

Error: NameError: file  line 28: name 'translate_x' is not defined

Can you please write a workable version, or place a link from the internet that shows a method using the class and calling methods using buttons? Nothing I have found from my internet search has anything like this and I'm just guessing where thigs should go.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as ml

class move_obj(object):
    def __int__(self, *args):
        self.cont = cont
        self.trans = trans
    def set_selected_name(self, *args):
        cont = cmds.ls (selection = True)
        return cont
    
    def translate_x(self, *args):
        trans = cmds.setAttr( cont[0] + '.translateX', 10) 
        print trans
          
        
if cmds.window ('window1', q = 1, ex = 1):
    cmds.deleteUI ('window1')

cmds.window ('window1',
             title = 'Translate Attr',
             sizeable = 0,
             resizeToFitChildren = True,
             menuBar = 1)

cmds.rowLayout (numberOfColumns = 3)

cmds.button (command = translate_x,
             backgroundColor = [1.0,
                                0.7300068665598535,
                                0.7300068665598535],
             label = 'Translate X')

cmds.showWindow ('window1')
```

Comment: You can check haggi key or my profile and look for ui + partial + functools. Many people has the same question about passing arguments into command